How to Change Extended Attributes of Files in Docker Images Across Different Architectures and Save Changes?
I'm working with Docker images across different architectures (x86_64 and ARM). I need to change the extended attributes (xattrs) of some exacutable files within these Docker images and save these changes when I dont know what each image supports.
I am familiar with basic Docker operations like building, running, and committing containers. However, I am unsure how to handle extended attributes specifically and ensure compatibility across different architectures. Additionally, I can't just open the Docker container, change the extended attributes, and commit these changes because I am uncertain about which commands or scripts (such as Python scripts or attr commands) are supported within the container.
Could someone provide a detailed method or best practices to achieve this? Any example commands or scripts that can be used inside the container to handle extended attributes would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried to run a the docker with bash but some dockers do not support the attr commands.
I have tried as well to create a python script which did not work as well as other dockers did not support the python script.
What else can I do?

Does chattr(1) not work in the way you expect?  You should almost never use docker commit.  Can you give a more specific example of the change you're trying to make: what base image are you starting from, what attribute are you trying to change (and why), and what trouble are you running into?

I tried to use the setfattr to change the extended attributes, not the chattr.
I working on multiple dockers, some are based ubuntu some are on python:3.7 but it should not matter as I seek a solution that is not dependent on the docker image itself.
I have a security application that approves executables only with a specific xattr, and I am working on a new feature that should support docker images. the issue is to apply the xattr to the executables inside of the docker images (some even have different architectures)

xattrs are filesystem-dependent, aren't they?  And a docker container, as I understand it, runs with the host system's native kernel on the native filesystem; they're not emulated.  So what happens if someone tries to run your container from a filesystem that simply doesn't support xattr at all?

@NateEldredge You are right it is filesystem-dependent, I am asuming that the filesystem will support extended atributes as it is one of the demands.

If you have access to the Dockerfiles themselves, you can make modifications to the Dockerfile to modify the extended attributes and ensure the build completes successfully. To ensure multi-arch compatibility for one Docker image, you can use the following methodology:

Create Two Unique Dockerfiles, one targeting x86 and the other targeting Arm.

Handle the extended attributes differently in each Dockerfile as needed.

Build the x86_64 Dockerfile on x86_64 hardware, and verify the image works as intended after building.

docker build -t my-image:amd64 .
docker push my-image:amd64


Build the Arm Dockerfile on Arm hardware, and verify the image works as intended after building.

docker build -t my-image:arm64 .
docker push my-image:arm64


Merge and Annotate the images using Docker Manifest (You can do this on either the x86 or Arm machine)

docker manifest create my-image:latest my-image:amd64 my-image:arm64
docker manifest annotate my-image:latest my-image:amd64 --os linux --arch amd64
docker manifest annotate my-image:latest my-image:arm64 --os linux --arch arm64
docker manifest push my-image:latest

At the end, you should have a my-image Docker image that works on both x86 and Arm hardware platforms, handling your extended attributes in architecture-specific ways as specified in your Dockerfiles.
An alternative is to use docker buildx, but you may run into issues with that multi-arch build process as you need to verify the extended attributes works directly on each machine's different architecture first. buildx builds multi-arch images from one machine.
To obtain an ARM machine for the build, you can select an Arm architecture machine on AWS or other cloud providers.
Hope this helps!

So you are suggesting to add the extended atributes from the docker file itself when building the docker images? What if I don't have access to the docker files or the build?

Correct; if you do not have access to the docker files or the build, what do you have access to changing? Can you describe your workflow a bit more?

Well I have tried to build on top of the given docker image, then add my extended attributes and I have tried you'r answer which solved the issue, Thank you!

You're welcome, glad it worked as expected!
